# Buying hyperspectral digital imagery?

Tags: imagery, image, geoeye, ikonos

I'm planning a research that includes couple Ikonos, QuickBird and GeoEye digital images.

Until now, I have had no luck getting answer from the official website of Landinfo.

Is there any other way to order this imagery, and is there a minimum order price (e.g. minimum $300)?

I also cannot see any 'Buy Now' options on their website.

Are the orders strictly via e-mail?

Comment: The pricing info is here: http://www.landinfo.com/satellite-imagery-pricing.html. Are you using the search application on the landinfo website in order to find archived imagery and purchase it?

Comment: @Radar thank you very much for the info. May I ask, have you also bought imagery that is not older than 90 days (meaning that it's not archived) using the search application?

Comment: Good question - I have only acquired older imagery (>1 year usually) using the search application.

Comment: www.imagery.geocento.com can also be used to find and order imagery. Pricing options are also specified in the search results section!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, you find the pricing for you imagery you're searching for by navigating [Buying Satellite Imagery:
Pricing Information for High Resolution Satellite Imagery](http://www.landinfo.com/satellite-imagery-pricing.html)

The minimum is provided in the notes section.

Here is an example of high resolution archive pricing:

[image]